# Jenkins using aws is not recognized as an internal or external command - Windows 10

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3

Jenkin Project - I configure the Build setup in Batch file in below statement
aws s3 cp ./dist/first-ci-project s3://first-ci-cd-project --recursive
but result is
'aws' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

But Command Prompt i run the above command its working good. Pl help me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the aws command in a jankins slave? If so please check whether aws cli command tool is installed on the slave and the location of the aws cli is added to the environment variables.

If you are running on the jenkins master, same as above. Please check if you have added the aws cli folder location is added as environment variable under jenkins master.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, I had make sure that the user with which aws CLI is installed is same as the one which Jenkins is using during the runtime